# How do I define JAVA_HOME variable for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

This is the first error I faced:

> No JVM installation found. Please install a 32-bit JDK. If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVE_HIME variable in Computer > System Properties > System Setting > Environment Variables.

Then I set the JAVA_HOME variable:
Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`
Variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0`

So I get another error:

> Failed to create JVM: error code -6. JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.9.0 If you already have a 32-bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in

What do I do next?

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again? Windows reloads its variables after a reboot or logoff/login.

Comment: I did restart my lap top but the same error comes up.

Answer (score 5):

After Settings restart your system [image]

Comment: you set the variable value to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65 What is that underline part at the end (_65)? I see that a lot but my folder name doesn't have that?

Comment: Only Studio would have to be restarted (if anything), after you set the variable. Open `cmd` and do `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to check if the variable's been set. to check your Java installation in `cmd`: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -version`

Answer (score 0):

I download the java from the oracle website, the downloaded file name is "jdk-7u79-windows-i586" and I changed variable value to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79" so the android studio started without any problem.

Comment: if your problem has been solved then choose correct answer and up vote